# Php Mail Functionality is not working in my server

Tags: php, mysql, mailer, parallels

I am using **Parallels Panel Sever** for mY site. It is windows Platform. I didnt work with IIS Server.Php Mail Functionality is not working. I got this Error.

**Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server. in C:\Inetpub\vhosts**

Please Help me how to solve this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: So please share your code segment

Comment: I given simple code for test process mail("xxx@gmail.com","Test","Test Mail");

Comment: And how is the php.ini config at the SMTP part?

Comment: In Php.ini SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

Comment: Check whether your port number of server is configured or not. In your code segment mail function is correct. But  some instance local mails not too long accept by domains. This is a common problem occur in windows server. You just check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243028/send-email-using-php-in-windows-server

Answer (score 0):

This may happens because you are using the php `mail()` command - which then sends it through the smtp server listed in the **php.ini** file.

However, when it gets to that server, it's saying "hey, you're not sending to me - you're sending to an external address. I'm not going to let you".

You can do one of two things to resolve this: 
- change the smtp server settings to allow relaying from the server's ip address 
- set up & use **'smtp authentication'** which should allow you to send anywhere. This will most likely be set up on the smtp server already so you just need to go to the Interspire Email Marketer settings page and put in the appropriate details in the **'SMTP Server'** section.

Comment: Could you tell me how to set SMTp authentication? In Php.ini file SMTP settings like this mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

Comment: Whats Interspire Email Marketer got do do with it, C&P fail perhaps?

Comment: Email Marketer on your server mail servers, That allow you to send mails via your mail names. Like mail at 123@23.com